# Why are there a finite number of Turing machines?

Tags: algorithm, theory, turing-machines, computation

In Michael Sipser's Introduction to the Theory of Computation, he states:

> "some languages are not decidable or even Turing recognizable, for the reason that there are uncountably many languages **yet only countably many Turing machines**. Because each Turing machine can recognize a single language and there are more languages than Turing machines, some languages are not recognized by any Turing machine" (178).

Isn't a Turing machine a hypothetical machine that can simulate any computer algorithm? And aren't there theoretically an infinite number of algorithms you could come up with? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this concept. An 'explain like I'm 5' answer would be greatly appreciated, but of course any help is better than none.

Comment: Would probably be better-suited at http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: But "countable" does not mean "finite".

Comment: I didn't know about cs.stackexchange, thanks. How would you differentiate between 'countable' and 'finite'?

Comment: A countable set is any whose elements can be put in one-to-one correspondence with the natural numbers (i.e. positive integers), or a subset thereof.  There are an infinite number of natural numbers, so...  (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable)

Comment: That makes sense, as the natural numbers are a countable set, but the size is infinite. Thanks

Comment: Take out a maths book from the library and check in to Hilbert's Hotel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a *countable* number of Turing machines. That doesn't mean there's a finite number. The set of Turing machines is countably infinite, which means that Turing machines can be numbered using natural numbers. That is you can create a 1-to-1 mapping between natural numbers and Turing machines.

Comment: +1. Just because you can count them does not mean you will ever finish counting.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are infinite number of Turing Machines, even of the same function. Say, Turing machine M is an implementation of a multiplication algorithm, i.e. given two integers such as 5 and 6, it outputs the product, 30. Then you may change M into another Turing machine M' simply by adding useless operations during the execution. Useless state, transition table item or symbols in the alphabet can also be added. Finally, you get a different Turing machine M', but it is of the same function as M. Repeat this process, you may get infinite number of Turing machines.

Remind that we may make the source code different by adding comments or useless statements.